# Changing status of <td> on click with javascript

Tags: javascript

I am making a conways game of life in javascript and having trouble getting my onclick implementation to work. It is supposed to change the life status of the cell when the td is clicked, but instead I am getting an error at my console that says : TypeError: World.tds is undefined. 
TLDR: Can't figure out why onclick won't work. World.tds[] is undefined for some reason.

Onclick implementation:

```
if (table !== null) {
for (var i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < 20; j++)
        World.tds[i][j].onclick = function() {
            if (World.tds[i][j].cells.alive) {
                World.tds[i][j].cells.alive = false;
            } else {
                World.tds[i][j].cells.alive = true;
            }
        };
}
}
```

Constructor and tds[] filling

```
var World = function() {
this.h = maxH;
this.w = maxW;
this.tds = [];
};

//generate the world in which the cells move
World.prototype.init = function() {
var row, cell;
for (var r = 0; r < this.h; r++) {
    this.tds[r] = [];
    row = document.createElement('tr');
    for (var c = 0; c < this.w; c++) {
        cell = document.createElement('td');
        this.tds[r][c] = cell;
        row.appendChild(cell);
    }
    table.appendChild(row);
}
};
```

Comment: missing brackets in second for loop

Comment: It would be interesting to know how init is called. It is important to know what this refers to.

Comment: Init is called in my HTML: var myWorld = new World();
        myWorld.init();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Problem Statement** - When you trigger the click handler, by that time values of i and j have updated to 20 each and World.tds[20][20] is undefined.

Update your code inside `for loop` to

```
(function(i,j) {
        World.tds[i][j].onclick = function() {
            if (World.tds[i][j].cells.alive) {
                World.tds[i][j].cells.alive = false;
            } else {
                World.tds[i][j].cells.alive = true;
            }
        };

})(i,j);
```

Comment: Still says: TypeError: World.tds is undefined

Comment: Can you replicate the error somewhere for me to look at. Additionally, is it giving World.tds[20][20] is undefined error

Comment: No it's not. I haven't gotten it to animate yet because I have been trying to figure out this onclick issue. here it is: http://people.emich.edu/gobeid1/gameOfLife/index.html

Comment: In place of `this.tds[i][j].cells.alive` you need to use `this.cells.alive` And as now there will be no dependability on i and j in the click handler, you will not even need the self executing function wrapper.

Comment: If you don't mind helping me more. I'm trying to call display() in my click function so the grid is automatically updating and it is saying: TypeError: this.display is not a function

Comment: The problem is `this` in click handler is not an instance of World and hence, display function is not available. You need to work up this.

Comment: Ok. So you think that I should change this to World in that function? That didn't work for me. When I call it outside of the inner function it still doesn't update.

Comment: @GriffinObeid - Well that is not the way to do it. I would suggest you to raise another question where you can elaborate this new problem of yours.